# jsonRootName missing while performing unit test case for spring hateoas

Tags: java, spring-boot, mockito, junit4, spring-hateoas

I have developed an rest service using spring-boot-starter-Hateoas, and I am able to get the json output properly as shown below:

```
"_embedded": {
   "bills": 
         {
          uid: "123"
          code: "0000"
```

And I need to write unit-test case for the same using mockito. The code I have written is as below.

ApplicationTest.java:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = Application.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
public class ApplicationTest {
```

BillControllerAutoTest:

```
public class BillControllerAutoTest {

private BillService mockBillService;
private MockMvc mockMvc;
private static final String BILL_UID = "99991";

@Before
public void setupController() {
           mockBillService= mock(BillService .class);
          BillController controller = new BillController (mockBillService);
    mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(controller).build();
}    

@Test
public void testGetBills() throws Exception {
    // some fake data
    final List<Bill> fakeBillList= new ArrayList<>();
    fakeBillList.add(BillFake.bill("1234"));

    when(mockBillService.getBills(BILL_UID))
            .thenReturn(fakeBillList.stream());

    // execute and verify
    mockMvc.perform(get("/bills/" + BILL_UID ))
            .andExpect(content().string(containsString("\"embedded\":{\"bills\"")))
```

BillController.java:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/bills/{billUid}", produces = "application/hal+json")
public class BillController extends BaseController {
private BillService billService;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "")
public ResponseEntity<Resources<Resource<Bill>>> getBills(@PathVariable String billUid) {
    return resourceListResponseEntity(
            () -> billService.getBills(billUid),
            bill-> createResource(billUid),
            resources -> resources.add(linkTo(methodOn(BillController .class)
                    .getBills(billUid)).withSelfRel()));
}
```

Dependencies:

```
dependencies {
compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-hateoas"
compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-ws"
compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator"

testCompile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
}
```

My build is failing with the following stackTrace:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Response content
Expected: a string containing "\"_embedded\":{\"bills\""
 but: was 
"content":[
   {
   uid: "123"
   code: "0000"
```

This means "_embedded : { bills" is not available in the response returned by mockMvc of the unit test. Am I missing any configuration, kindly let me know. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I've answered very similar question here: [Spring's MockMVC Responses Don't Match Browser Response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33127031/springs-mockmvc-responses-dont-match-browser-response)

In a nutshell: spring HATEOAS adds additional configuration for rendering hal properly (as described here: http://docs.spring.io/spring-hateoas/docs/0.19.0.RELEASE/reference/html/#configuration). In your tests you have to apply this configuration manually. Check the first link for details on how to do it