# Spring's MockMVC Responses Don't Match Browser Response

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-hateoas

For some reason, my Spring controller is returning different responses if I access it via a browser or via my MockMVC test class.  **Could someone help me spot why?**

First the controller method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = APPLICATIONS_ROOT, method = GET)
  public HttpEntity<ApplicationsListResource> listApplications(@PageableDefault(page = DEFAULT_START,
      size = DEFAULT_HITS_PER_PAGE) Pageable pageable) {
    Page<Application> applications = applicationRepository.findAll(pageable);
    ApplicationsListResource applicationListResource = new ApplicationsListResource(applications, pageable);
    return new ResponseEntity<ApplicationsListResource>(applicationListResource, HttpStatus.OK);
  }
```

Obviously there's a few unknown classes in there. `ApplicationListResource` extends `ResourceSupport` and contains a list of `ApplicationResource` called `applications`.  This `ApplicationResource` also extends `ResourceSupport`.

When I access the code via the browser, I'll get something along the lines of:

```
{
  "_links": {
    "self": {
      "href": "http://localhost:10000/applications{?page,size,sort}",
      "templated": true
    }
  },
  "_embedded": {
    "applications": [{
      "displayname": "One",
      "description": "My Test Application!",
      "locations": ["http://foo.com"],
      "_links": {
        "self": { "href": "http://localhost:10000/applications/one" }
      }
    }, {
      ...
    }]
  },
  "page": {
    "size": 20,
    "totalElements": 7,
    "totalPages": 1,
    "number": 0
  }
}
```

Looks HATEOAS compliant to me.  But when I go via a MockMVC request...

```
getMockMvc().perform(get(APPLICATIONS_ROOT)).andExpect(status().isOk()).andExpect(content().contentType(MediaTypes.HAL_JSON)).andExpect(jsonPath("$._embedded.applcations", hasSize(5))).andReturn();
```

The responses have no HATEOAS compliant elements in them so my tests fail on the jsonPath check:

```
{
  "page" : 0,
  "size" : 10,
  "sort" : null,
  "total" : 5,
  "applications" : [ {
    "name" : "one",
    "version" : "1.0",
    ...
```

I've tried changing the ContentType on the GET request for the MockMVC method but it makes no difference. In the browser, I'm not setting any specific content type, headers etc.

I know the MockMVC class makes it HTTP requests with certain differences from the usual RestTemplate so perhaps it's something like this? Can anyone see anything obvious I am missing?

I will add additional code if needs be but it would have made the question even more long winded than it is currently.

Comment: Look into the MockMVC configuration - I think there are additional config options that you are missing (maybe to support the HATEOS stuff). Sorry I don't have a real answer, just a gut feeling.

Comment: My suggestion is to see all headers that are set from the request initiated from browser, because every browser sets different headers and then to set the same headers in the mockMvc request and especially look for `Accept` header. The response from mockMvc looks like unwrapped and properties started with `_` are renamed...

Comment: @cjstehno - Nothing wrong with a gut feeling :) I'll have a look into them.
NikolayRusev - I noticed the fact that the responses do contain different keys for the pagination. That's what I'm currently looking into to see if sheds any light on the issue.

Comment: this is absolutely very strange behaviour I will follow this thread :) can you post your mockmvc config?

Comment: I'll try and get a example project illustrating the behaviour on GitHub. Will be a bit easier than trying to post a load of code here.

Answer (score 3):

Spring HATEOAS adds additional configuration for rendering hal properly, check this for details: http://docs.spring.io/spring-hateoas/docs/0.19.0.RELEASE/reference/html/#configuration.

In a nutshell it adds proper `MixIn`s added by `Jackson2HalModule` and `HalHandlerInstantiator` to the `ObjectMapper`. It's all configured in `HypermediaSupportBeanDefinitionRegistrar.java` (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-hateoas/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/hateoas/config/HypermediaSupportBeanDefinitionRegistrar.java)

If you're using standalone mockMvc configuration you have to configure the `ObjectMapper` manually to mimic spring's behaviour. I ran into same problem and ended up adding following configuration to my tests:

```
mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(controller)
        .setMessageConverters(
                new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter(configureObjectMapper()))
        .build();
```

and

```
private ObjectMapper configureObjectMapper() {
    return Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.json()
        .modules(new Jackson2HalModule())
        .handlerInstantiator(new Jackson2HalModule.HalHandlerInstantiator(
            new DelegatingRelProvider(
                OrderAwarePluginRegistry.create(Arrays.asList(
                    new EvoInflectorRelProvider(),
                    new AnnotationRelProvider()))),
            null))
        .build();
}
```

Comment: Any insight on how to convert this solution for the newer 1.x version of HATEOAS?